# How I can use tabs instead spaces for emacs ruby-mode?

Tags: ruby, emacs

I try to use tabs instead spaces in emacs with ruby-mode, but I can't do it. There is my fragment from my emacs dot-file

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
```

but it doesn't works, I guess this have trouble by reason ruby-mode. And how I can fix it?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: `(setq indent-tabs-mode)` is malformed. You need a second argument: the value to assign.

Comment: @Drew yes, I know. Sorry, I didnt see error in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't write Ruby code, so don't know about the ruby-mode in particular. But it seems that you need to wrap your setting by a hook to the ruby-mode. How about trying this?

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
            (setq tab-width 2)))
```

Comment: thanks, I trying it now, but I get this error
`Wrong type argument: symbolp, (robe-mode inf-ruby-minor-mode)`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I forgot the ' symbol before ruby-mode-hook. Can you try it again? I updated on the answer as well.

Comment: thanks! but update please your answer. It works when `(setq indent-tabs-mode)` gets the second argument `t` :)